# What is good for design administrative website?

Tags: php, mobile-website, web-deployment

What is the best way for design administrative side of Travel website, Is it good for include mobile and desktop design? Or better only develop desktop design? i mean based on new technologies?

Comment: Unfortunately this is opinion-based, therefore not suitable for Stack Overflow. Voted to close.

Comment: one that works for your administrative taks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is highly opinion-based, but I would rather have only desktop design for administrative side for any website.

- For administrative side, there are a lot of input and usually it looks very messy to fit in mobile design.
- Time spent on mobile design should be better spend on improving other feature of administrative side.
- Most smartphone nowadays can render complex HTML as desktop computer. So having desktop only design does not mean mobile device cannot properly view the admin side.